# How can I style individual numbers in a countdown clock on my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Helloooo...I've been tasked with creating a web page that contains a count down clock.  I have managed to create the clock with HTML and Javascript but what I am having trouble with is the formatting.  The client wants the days, hours and minutes in separate individual circles.  Not animated, just plain.  I've tried a few things with no results.  I thought maybe if I created a separate clock for the Days, hours and minutes, that that would work, but when I do this, the clocks disappear. Would love some advice.  Thanks a million.

The code for the clock I used is as follows:

```
<script>
var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 14, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();


var x = setInterval(function() {


var now = new Date().getTime();


var distance = countDownDate - now;


var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
+ minutes + "m ";


if (distance < 0) {
clearInterval(x);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "We Are Live!";
}
}, 1000);
</script>
```

The CSS I used is as follows but I can only get that to work when I just have one time from the clock, like just the days for instance.

```
.demo{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font: 30px cantata;
    display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: provide a working snippet of what you have and include a picture or drawing (wire frame) of what you would like

Answer (score 0):

Just place the hours, minutes, and seconds within their own containers and style them separately, e.g:

```html
<div id="demo">
    <span id="hours"/>:
    <span id="minutes"/>:
    <span id="seconds"/>
</div>
```